# Aadhar Authentication RD Service for fingerprint IOS

Tags: ios, swift, fingerprint, biometrics

I am developing app with Aadhaar payment which needs fingerprint authentication using Aadhaar UIDAI. but in market there are lot of fingerprint scanner devices. each device has their own rd service which return scan data(new format PID data).
This is easily can be done in Android.
How i integrates same for iOS devices?

Comment: You cannot access fingerprint data on iOS. It is encrypted and stored in the Secure Enclave. An app can request a biometric authentication via the Local Authentication framework.  It gets back a yes/no based on whether the biometric process (TouchID or FaceID) was successful

Comment: RD service like MORPHO device used in Android.

Comment: Unless they make a version with MFi support or Bluetooth Low Energy it is unlikely that you will find an iOS solution